# Specify database within query using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to SQL and Oracle SQL Developer.

I have two databases on the same server and have connections to them.

I have two queries I want to run against both databases and hoping to use the 'Run Script' option to produce the output.

At the moment I'm selecting one database and running one query, and then selecting another database and running the second query.

Is there a way to specify the database in my SELECT or FROM sections of my query?
I have tried to search for this but was unable to find anything, I was hoping for something as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1 myTable

SELECT * FROM DB2 myTable
```

If not, how do you run two queries against two different databases at the same time?

Comment: Do you have, or can you create, a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-a-distributed-database.html#GUID-B5950167-35F8-4C88-B063-382E0290CB53) between them? (Assuming they actually are two databases; not two schemas in the same database.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, going to do some research on this, first I heard of it and I'm not sure. Is it like a local setting for my account only and not making changes to any of the DB's/system? Im not a DB engineer, I just need to query data for reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

In your worksheet, you can have something like this -

[image]

What's happening?

1. My SQL worksheet is associated with a connection to HR on ORCL
2. In my worksheet I have a connect statement, followed by a query, followed by another connect, followed by another query
3. I run this using the script engine
4. SQL Developer makes a connection, runs the query, prints the results, and follows that through to the end, so two connections, two queries, one set of results
5. At the very end, the connection to orclcdb is DISCONNECTED, and the SQL worksheet connection goes back to the HR on ORCL - as shown in the indicator in the upper right hand corner

   ```
   clear screen -- clears the script output panel
   set sqlformat ansiconsole -- tells the editor to best fit the output, not based on the size of the columns

   connect hr/oracle@localhost:1521/orcl
   select * from regions;

   connect system/oracle@localhost:1521/orclcdb
   select * from dba_pdbs;
   ```